# Java object not added to ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, immutability, mutable

I have a problem. I am writing code for an ecosystem with fish and I am trying to add a new Fish object to an existing fish ArrayList . However, when I check the ArrayList it turns out to be empty? Thoughts?

```
public void addFish(Fish f){
    ArrayList<Fish> fishplusone = new ArrayList<Fish>(fish.size());
    if (landscape[f.getRow()][f.getCol()] != ROCK) {
        for (Fish otherfish: this.fish) {
                if(otherfish.getRow() == f.getRow() && otherfish.getCol() == f.getCol()) {
                    throw new IllegalFishPositionException(IllegalFishPositionException.TWO_FISH_IN_ONE_PLACE); 

                }
                else {
                    fishplusone.add(otherfish); 
                    }
                fishplusone.add(f);
                fish = fishplusone;
                }

            }
```

Comment: Please edit your post so that it's sensibly indented, and remove extraneous code. Ideally, you should show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We've no idea what the `fish` variable is, for example.

Comment: Maybe `landscape[f.getRow()][f.getCol()]` is a `ROCK` or `this.fish` is empty (assuming you don't get any exceptions).

Comment: does it always throw the exception?

Comment: no it compiles without throwing any exceptions but the fish arraylist is empty

Comment: if this.fish is empty wouldn't one fish still be added to the arraylist?

Comment: No, if there are no objects in an List an enhanced for will not be executed.

Answer (score 0):

You create a new ArrayList each time: `ArrayList<Fish> fishplusone = new ArrayList<Fish>(fish.size());`

Isn't it easier to do your checks first and then add it to an existing List?